# CSS Multiple Selectors Jumps to top of page

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have 5 labels and 5 radios connected inside a div, and the CSS is making div1 hide when I click on radio3 for example. Without the div wrapping the labels and radios it works, but with it, I can't seem to make it work. When it's wrapped, I click on a label and it jumps to the top of the page. I tried every selector I could think of.

CSS:

```css
input[type=radio] {
   position: absolute;
   top: -9999px;
   left: -9999px;
}
label { 
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 60px 0 10px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Default State */
.hombre, .mujer, .nino, .bicis, .calzado{
 display: none;
}
/* Toggled State */
.cat input[type=radio]#menu-hombre:checked ~ div.hombre, .cat input[type=radio]#menu-mujer:checked ~ div.mujer, .cat input[type=radio]#menu-nino:checked ~ div.nino, .cat input[type=radio]#menu-bicis:checked ~ div.bicis, .cat input[type=radio]#menu-calzado:checked ~ div.calzado {
 display:block;
}
.cat input[type=radio]#menu-hombre ~ div.mujer, div.nino, div.bicis, div.calzado {
 display: none;
}
.cat input[type=radio]#menu-mujer ~ div.hombre, div.nino, div.bicis, div.calzado {
 display: none;
}
.cat input[type=radio]#menu-nino ~ div.hombre, div.mujer, div.bicis, div.calzado {
 display: none;
}
.cat input[type=radio]#menu-bicis ~ div.hombre, div.nino, div.mujer, div.calzado {
 display: none;
}
.cat input[type=radio]#menu-calzado ~ div.hombre, div.nino, div.bicis, div.mujer {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="cat">
 <label for="menu-hombre"><i class="fa fa-male"></i>Hombre</label>
 <input type="radio" id="menu-hombre" name="tallas">
 <label for="menu-mujer"><i class="fa fa-female"></i>Mujer</label>
 <input type="radio" id="menu-mujer" name="tallas">
 <label for="menu-nino"><i class="fa fa-child"></i>Niño</label>
 <input type="radio" id="menu-nino" name="tallas">
 <label for="menu-bicis"><i class="fa fa-bicycle"></i>Bicis</label>
 <input type="radio" id="menu-bicis" name="tallas">
 <label for="menu-calzado"><i class="fa fa-street-view"></i>Calzado Y Accesorios</label>
 <input type="radio" id="menu-calzado" name="tallas">
</div>
<div class="hombre"><p>Hombre</p></div>
<div class="mujer"><p>Mujer</p></div>
<div class="nino"><p>Niño</p></div>
<div class="bicis"><p>Bicis</p></div>
<div class="calzado"><p>Calzado Y Accesorios</p></div>
```

The idea here is to show div hombre when I click on the label Hombre, and hide all the other divs. The same with the other labels and corresponding divs. Without the div `cat`, it works. With it, it jumps to the top of the page. Any idea?

Comment: I did not get what exactly are you trying to achieve, please elaborate more...

Comment: sorry, explained better at the bottom

Comment: I'm not sure this is the issue here, but your CSS has `cat` instead of `.cat`

Comment: it's not, to put the here with the problem I wrote cat on all the necessary places and I forgot the dot. The result is the same. Sorry

Comment: This is because the adjacent sibling selector (~) works only for sibling elements (elements that have the same parent element). You would have to move all your other divs inside `cat` too.

Comment: ok, it kinda works, it still jumps to the top of the page...

Comment: You can try using `display: none` for the `input[type=radio]` instead of the absolute position trick.

Comment: It's not exactly what I need since I eventually need to separate the labels and radios from the other divs, but thanks for the help :D